# How to delete files older than X days and print a list of removed files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Suppose the following call in a script:

```bash
find $dir/$CACHE_DIR_SUBPATH -type f -mtime +$RETENTION_DAYS -delete
```

Is there a neat way to print the file names that are going to be deleted or is the best option to call `find` twice like so:

```bash
find $dir/$CACHE_DIR_SUBPATH -type f -mtime +$RETENTION_DAYS
find $dir/$CACHE_DIR_SUBPATH -type f -mtime +$RETENTION_DAYS -delete
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply introduce into the `find` command line the `-print` option.

In others words:

```bash
find $dir/$CACHE_DIR_SUBPATH -type f -mtime +$RETENTION_DAYS -print -delete
```

The alternative way maybe:

```bash
find $dir/$CACHE_DIR_SUBPATH -type f -mtime +$RETENTION_DAYS -exec echo "Deleting file '{}'..."; rm {} \;
```

Comment: I would put the `-print` after the `-delete`, so that it prints the deleted files and not the attempts at deletion

Comment: No problem you can.